# Embedded Vimeo Videos to Play Automatically

Tags: javascript, php

with my code below, I play videos one after the other but the videos are stored locally and I would like to use integrated vimeo videos on a page and have them start playing as soon as the page is open and when the first video has finished, the second one starts.
in my code i have an array (playlist[]) of src ... is it possible to replace the source with the source of my Vimeo videos or no?

```
 <video id="headervideo" class="video">
                            <source id="videoFile" width="100%" height="100%" />
                          Your browser does not support the video tag.
                     </video>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //==============================
        var track = 0
        var playlist = [{src: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/240512614?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0', type: 'video/mp4'}, {src: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/240289181', type: 'video/mp4'}]


        //==============================
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('headervideo').addEventListener('ended', function () {
                track++
                track = (track > (playlist.length - 1)) ? 0 : track
                //alert(track)
                playMovie(playlist[track])
            }, false)
            playMovie(playlist[track])
        })
        //==============================
        playMovie = function (movie) {
            $('#videoFile')
                .prop('src', movie.src)
                .prop('type', movie.type)

            document.getElementById('headervideo').load()
            document.getElementById('headervideo').play()
        }
         //==============================
     </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing them?

Comment: yes, but it's not work, I thought maybe I did not do it well, so I ask if it's possible to do it

Comment: You should publish the broken code that you've tried rather than working code that doesn't show your attempt.  We can't fix your broken code if we can't see it.

Comment: ok thanks you , i do it now

Comment: can you help me  @jmargolisvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, according to vimeo documentation

**EDIT**

I replace the code posted before with a working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="video-container"></div>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

        var videos = ['59777392', '19231868', '202791609']; //videos ids

        var options = {
            width: 640
        };

        playMovie(null, videos, options)
    })

    var playMovie = function(player, videos, options) {

        if (!videos.length) {
            return false;
        }

        var video = videos.shift();

        if(!player){
            options.id = video;
            player = new Vimeo.Player('video-container', options);
            player.play();
            player.on('ended', function(){
                playMovie(player, videos, options)
            })
        }else{
            player.loadVideo(video)
                .then(function(){
                    player.play();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tested firstly with autoplay in the options but it starts automatically only the first two videos. I solved the problem by calling the play function on each video

Comment: it's not work ... I make alert in code....after var video = videos.shift(); he return to  playMovie(player, videos)  in first function then he quit

Comment: he does'n load video

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Can you please mark the answer as the correct one if this is still the case? I'm pretty new on stackoverflow I really need this.
Thank you